# How to make RadioButtons to generate me some locations in a Tourist Guide on Android

Tags: android, radio-button, radio-group

[In this image is my first tab of my application. When I press 'Monument' should return me only the places who are monuments(in this case only first item)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ErcO1.png)I have an Android application and I have something like Tourist Guide and I made 3 `RadioGroups` with 4 `RadioButtons` for everyone. I have some code for this buttons, but I dont know why my app crashed when i'm trying to select a button. Each location has a category where are more locations with another id for RadioButton. For example in class `CategoryVisitFragment` i have locations for visit where I had 4 different types of `radiobuttons`.

I tried to get data from `strings.xml`  for places. This data must return image, name, description and details. I don't know why the rootView returns null.

```
    private void updateFragment() {
    RadioGroup radioGroup1 = findViewById(R.id.mRadioGroup);
    RadioButton checkedRbGroup1 = findViewById(radioGroup1.getCheckedRadioButtonId());

    RadioGroup radioGroup2 = findViewById(R.id.mRadioGroup2);
    RadioButton checkedRbGroup2 = findViewById(radioGroup2.getCheckedRadioButtonId());

    Fragment currentFragment = (Fragment) getCurrentFragment();

    View rootView = currentFragment.getView();//rootView este null si nu am reusit sa-mi dau seama de ce
    ListView listView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.list);//NPE
    ArrayAdapter<PlaceToVisit> arrayAdapter = (ArrayAdapter)listView.getAdapter();
    arrayAdapter.clear();

    if (currentFragment instanceof CategoryVisitFragment
            && checkedRbGroup1.getText().toString().equals("Monument")) {
        arrayAdapter.add(new PlaceToVisit(getString(R.string.visit_item1_name), R.drawable.catedrala_tm,
                getString(R.string.visit_item1_description),getString(R.string.visit_item1_information)));

    }
    arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

This is for creating locations and the dates for visit_item1_name, visit_item1_description, visit_item1_details are in strings

```
   // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.category_list, container, false);

    // Create the list for the Visit Category. All texts are stored as Strings.
    final ArrayList<PlaceToVisit> listOfPlaces = new ArrayList<PlaceToVisit>();

    listOfPlaces.add(new PlaceToVisit(getString(R.string.visit_item1_name), R.drawable.catedrala_tm,
            getString(R.string.visit_item1_description),getString(R.string.visit_item1_information)));
```

I expect the output of selecting RadioButton which had `android:id="@+id/monumentRadioButton"` or `android:text="Monument"` to return the place with all of details for `catedrala_tm`

Comment: please edit your message with the error log

Comment: Show the logcat so that we can understand your error

Comment: I dont have en error.. my app crash when i press the radiobutton. The code is functionally

Comment: i put an image above